# How do I update the text of a div inside of a table/form in Jquery inside of a dialog box?

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui

I have a div inside of a table which is inside of a form that I would like to update

```
<form id="login_form" method="post" action="#" onsubmit="return false;"><table> 
<tr><td>Username</td><td><input type="text" name="name" id="login_name"></td></tr>
<tr><td>Password</td><td><input type="password" name="password" id="login_password"></td></tr>
<tr><td><input type="checkbox" name="keep_logged" id="login_keep" checked></td><td>Keep me logged in on this computer</td></tr>
<tr><td colspan=2><br><INPUT type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit" onclick="submitLogin();">
<INPUT type="reset" name="Cancel" value="Cancel" id="login_cancel"></td></tr>
<tr><td colspan=2><div id="result_div"></div></td></tr>
</table>
</form>
```

I have tried numerous methods to update that div, but I can not seem to get it to work.
For example:

```
$("div#result_div").html("My text is changed!");
$("#result_div").html("My text is changed!");
document.getElementById('result_div').innerHTML = 'My Text is changed!';
```

I've tried changing it from a div to a span with the same results.  If I move the div outside of the table/form the text update works perfectly, so I'm fairly certain my code is being excuted correctly.

Any help would be apperciated.

Thanks.

edit:  I realized this is inside of a Jquery-ui dialog box, I'm sorry for ommiting that piece of information orginally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code snippet works for me, so there's nothing inherently wrong with what you're doing. You've omitted some crucial detail from the surrounding code...

- Where are you trying to do the update from? `$("#result_div")` will only work if you have that `<script>` below the `<div>` element on the page, or if you do it from a `$(document).ready(...)` callback function so it only executes after the page is loaded.
- There's only one element with `id="result_div"`, right?
- If you display `$("#result_div").html()` immediately after setting it, is it set correctly?
- Do you see any JavaScript errors in your browser's JS error log/console from other scripts on the page?
- You're not serving up the page with an XHTML `<!DOCTYPE>` are you? Or with the `application/xhtml+xml` MIME type?
- What gets displayed if you just do `alert($("#result_div").length)`?

Comment: If I do an the alert you suggested the result is 1.  The page is not xhtml, and I the script is loaded before the <div> element on the page.  No errors in the error console at all.

Comment: alert($("#result_div").length);
    $("#result_div").html("My text is changed!");
    alert($("#result_div").length);
    $("#result_div").html();
    alert($("#result_div").length);
I tried that and received alerts of 1, 1, and 1.  I only have 1 #result_div element.

Comment: Hm. Did the alert($("#result_div").html()) work also? And what if you do a setTimeout(function() { alert($("#result_div").html()); }, 1000) to display it again 1 second later?

Comment: It looks like #result_div was being reset at the end of the JS function it was in.  That setTimeout function showed it being blank, although immediately after it was set the alert did show it, I'm still not entirely sure how, but I rewrote a bit of it and it works  perfectly now.  Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you have some malformed html.  You're missing a `</td>` tag after "Keep me logged in ...".  I don't know if that will solve it, but it might help.

Comment: Oops, I missed that, I corrected the missing </td></tr> but unfortunately I still have the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like it works,

http://jsbin.com/esibi/

You're calling the function to populate #result_div after the html has loaded right?

Answer (score 0):

$("#result_div").text("My text is changed!");

Make sure the code is executing, with no errors on the page.